# Sort a vector with another vector using lambda function

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, lambda

In the code below, I get segmentation fault. I think the problem is with indexing but I don't understand why. Is it possible to use `std::sort` and lambda function to sort a vector based on another vector?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> A = {"b", "a", "c"};
    std::vector<int> B = {2, 1, 3};

    std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A),
            [&](const std::string& t1, const std::string& t2)
            {
            return B[&t1-A.data()] > B[&t2-A.data()]; // problem could be here!
            });

    std::cout << A[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << A[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << A[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&t1-A.data()` that does not look like it should be used to index into a vector

Comment: you know that `&t1` is a memory address?

Comment: @tobi303 it makes sense to find what element t1 is.

Comment: @tobi303 `std::vector::data` returns a pointer to a `std::vector` s internal buffer.

Comment: @JakeFreeman I dont understand what you mean

Comment: @George that doesnt make this way of indexing less wrong, does it?

Comment: You're not taking into account that elements can move around during the sort.

Comment: @tobi303 It doesn't, I just didn't understand why/how "you know that &t1 is a memory address?" is relevant? :)

Comment: What is the real goal?  Is it to sort a vector of indices into the `A` vector without having to actually sort the `A` vector?  If so, the approach is incorrect.

Comment: @George yes, actually it took me a minute to realize that `&t1 - A.data()` can result in a valid index, but still it is as obfuscated as it can get imho

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to sort `B` and then order the elements of `A` accordingly. But mainly I would like to know why I get segmentation fault.

Comment: @Shibli -- *I would like to know why I get segmentation fault.* -- What if you printed out the value of `&t1 - A.data()`?  Does that value equate to a valid index into the `B` array?  [Look at this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/462ee4b63ffd58da). Basically all it took was a simple `cout` to see right away this would not have worked.  Again, if your goal is to have `B` to act as an index array into `A`, then the links provided in the comments shows how to do this.

Comment: @Shibli -- [Here is proof of the crash, using `at()`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8516060e6cdd115a).  So that answers your question -- the array index is out of bounds, way, way, out of bounds,.

Comment: @Shibli -- [Is this what you're really trying to accomplish](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbc26f8125074e11)?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing your way to get the index a simple way to do it.

```
std::sort(std::begin(A), std::end(A),
        [&](const std::string& t1, const std::string& t2)
        {
          int index1, index2;
          for(int i = 0; i<A.size(); i++) {
            if(&A[i] == &t1) index1 = i;
            if(&A[i] == &t2) index2 = i;
          }
        return B[index1] > B[index2];
        });
```

This way is safe and ensures that it gets the right index. After testing it the output is `C \n B \n A` which is what I think you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this method increases the sort runtime to `O(n^2 logn)`

Comment: @AlbinPaul I don't think runtime is an issue here but I will optimize it.

Comment: This looks like it turns `std::sort` into an `O(n^2)` time complexity from a logarithmic one.  Imagine if `A` had 1000 elements.

Comment: I would like to know why my method fails.

Comment: FYI, the output is incorrect in different cases. For example, an input of `b a c` and `3 2 1` [gives me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PUGBqo9cQjrujijf) an output of `b c a` with GCC. Adding `-O2` to that causes a segfault.

Comment: You should get `b c a`. Adding `-02`?